# Administering Anti-biotics to elderly people

Tags: medications, antibiotics, prescription

Is there anything wrong in administering antibiotics to a patient as old as 65, twice within 2 months? The patient had boil in the arm-pit the first time and was required to take the antibiotics, 4 times a day, consecutively for five(5) days. Most recently, the boil re-appeared again and the same medication has been suggested again.

Comment: A fairly large amount of information is easily found just in Google: http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Antibiotics-penicillins/Pages/Side-effects.aspx, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibiotics#Side-effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the same antibiotic whithin a short time does possibly increase the risk of  drug resistance so you should generally consult a doctor in this case. The boil re-appearing is also not the best sign, as could mean that the previous eradication was not successful. You may need an other drug or surgical approach.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Answers supported by references are strongly recommended here on health stackexchange, so if you edited your answer to include some, that would be great :-). Thanks!